# With which IDE develop in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I must have a IDE for VB6.

I can't use DotNet, because I cannot install a Framework on a computer, on which I will use my application and I know VB.Net, so I decide to use VB6 (I am open for other options).

Which IDE do you prefer for VB6?

Comment: Um, perhaps the one that comes with VB6?

Comment: The only thing VB6 and VB.NET only have in common is the syntax.  Nearly none of the libraries are the same so knowing .NET might not be as useful as you hope.

Comment: To do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844683/which-language-shouod-i-take-closed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, except Microsoft's Visual Basic 6.0, I don't know any.

By the way, Microsoft's support of VB6 is now over since 2008, you might consider using another language.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by support: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx  This means VB6 is supported until at least 2020 http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=14481

Comment: @Bob. +1 for that comment. The VB6 runtime is still fully supported.

Comment: When will it stop?  Hard to say.  The next Windows isn't close enough to release yet for an announcement about its support of VB6 programs.

Answer (score 2):

The ide is the Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 ide. I am not aware of any other ide.

See the [resource center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788229.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can get vb 5.0 cce for free.
http://www.thevbzone.com/vbcce.htm

details:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165524

also check this out
[Alternative IDE for VB6 and VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226565/alternative-ide-for-vb6)

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Basic Tools For Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6a06be60-1198-486e-9bce-6ace36b24316%20Visual%20Basic%20Tools%20For%20Visual%20Studio) lets you open vb6 project in visual studio 2012/2013, with basic outlining, syntax coloring, and a few more things.

Its a work in progress, but if like me you have some living dead vb6 programs to maintain, it's... intriguing. Except there's no GUI editor, no debugging. I fear these points (especially debugging) are deal breakers. (Of course, I understand that not everything is possible).