# Is there a way to compile VB6 in 2018?

Tags: compilation, vb6, vb6-migration, legacy-code

The reason I need this is I'm porting a VB6 app and I'm getting a very small difference in the arithmetic between VB6 and C#. I just need to test a couple calculations. The one I'm most interested in is how this comes out:

```
Round(2.24984, 1)
```

If that comes out to 2.3 in VB6 I'm done, it's figured out. But if not there are a couple steps leading up to that which could also be the problem.

An online VB6 fiddle would be ideal but I can install a virtual machine if I have to.

Comment: It comes out to 2.2 in VB6.

Comment: It comes out to 2.2 in VB.Net (2017).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what question you're asking. You can certainly install VB6 if you have a copy. Are you asking about where you can buy a copy (which I think would be off-topic for Stack Overflow), or are you having some problem installing it or something?

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. you know how they have online C#, C++, Java, Rust, etc. etc. fiddles? I was hoping for something like that for VB6. Aside from that though I'm open to any way of installing any VB6 compiler. Of course I could go buy one off ebay and find a computer it will run on but I was looking for an easier way of doing it.

Comment: VB6 uses banker's rounding, but that doesn't really matter with your example - it only comes into play with rounding halves up or down based on the odd/even value of the preceding digit, I believe.  Since your number isn't exactly 2.25 it will round down to 2.2.

Comment: Visual Basic for Applications is 95% equivalent to VB6 so you could try a macro in Office (Word, Excel etc) if you have a copy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative IDE for VB6 and VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226565/alternative-ide-for-vb6-and-vba)

Comment: Are you really asking about the rounding behavior? Or are you asking about the compiler?

Comment: I need to compile it so I can see the rounding behavior.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot compile a VB6 project directly in Visual Studio 2017.

What you can do is open the project in Visual Studio 2008 and migrate it to VB.Net using the Visual Basic Update Wizard. (The migrated code will likely have errors you will have to fix yourself.) Once this is done, you can open the migrated project in Visual Studio 2017 (the current production release of Visual Studio).

Comment: VB6 IDE works fine on Win 10. Have to run as admin. And complex programs will need to be recomiled on Win 10.

Comment: Do you know if the only place to get a copy of the IDE is second hand (like ebay or craigslist?).

Comment: Visual Basic 6 Enterprise is available as an MSDN download with MSDN Enterprise subscriptions.

Comment: An alternative is to buy it used on eBay. There are usually several legitimate copies for sale there at any time.